# Qt : multiple defined symbols found

Tags: c++, qt, symbols

This is a Qt project which, once built, results in a dll AnTS_Core.dll
so I have:

AnTs_Core.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Globals.h" // my global values
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void load();
}
void load()
{

    mainDispatcher = new Dispatcher();
}
```

The Global header file which contains all main objects as global(because I want to call an object method from an other object):

Globals.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H
#include "AnTS_Types.h"
#include "Dispatcher.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    Dispatcher *mainDispatcher;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

The Dispatcher : header file

```
#ifndef DISPATCHER_H
#define DISPATCHER_H
#include "AnTS_Types.h"
#include "Device.h"
#include <list>
#include <windows.h>
class Dispatcher
{
public:
    Dispatcher();
    ~Dispatcher();
private:
    std::list<Device*> _devices;
};
#endif
```

Dispatcher.cpp :

```
#include "Dispatcher.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex>
#include "Device/DEV_Struct.h"
Dispatcher::Dispatcher()
{
}
```

and the device (Dispatcher contains a list of devices)

Device.h

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H

#include <windows.h>
#include "Device/DEV_Struct.h"
#include "AnTS_Types.h"
#define ANTS_DEVICE_NAME_LENGHT 64
class Device
{
public:
    Device(char*);
    ~Device();
};
#endif // DEVICE_H
```

Device.cpp

```
#include "../Includes/Device.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Globals.h"

Device::Device(char* dllPath)
{
}
```

The errors are:

> LNK2005 _mainDispatcher already defined in AnTS_Core.cpp.obj
>
> LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found

The errors disappear when I comment the line `#include "Globals.h"` in Device.cpp. But I want to access to global variables (to an other Dispatcher for example or to another object) from the device.cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a classical [declaration vs definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) issue - you have defined the variable  `mainDispatcher` in the header and thus every compilation unit that includes this header winds up with a definition, where what you want is to declare the variable in the header as `extern` (this will only inform every compilation unit that includes the header that such variable exists):

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H
#include "AnTS_Types.h"
#include "Dispatcher.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    extern Dispatcher *mainDispatcher;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // GLOBALS_H`
```

And you should place the actual definition `Dispatcher* mainDispatcher` in one of your `.cpp` files.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much ! I had already tried the "extern" but I didn't place the definition in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Dispatcher *mainDispatcher;` in your `Globals.h`, this way every compilation unit which includes this header creates its own instance of this symbol. Declare `extern Dispatcher *mainDispatcher;` in `Globals.h`, and add `Dispatcher *mainDispatcher;` in `AnTs_Core.cpp`. This way you will have one symbol for `AnTs_Core.cpp` compilation unit, but others will see it through extern declaration.